# Symfony doctrine versionnable behaviour ignore fields

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, behavior

I have a versionable table in my schema. I want it not to be versioned when i change status for example, but versioned when i change shippingPrice.

```
MyOrder:   
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    Versionable:
      versionColumn: version
      className: %CLASS%Version
      auditLog: true   
    columns:
      userId: { type: integer, notnull: true }
      status: {type: enum, values: ["status1", "status2"]}
      shippingPrice: { type: float, notnull: true }
      #more columns
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This article might be of some interest:
http://blog.solutionset.com/wpmu/2009/08/26/doctrine-with-nested-i18n-versionable/

The author wants to nest I18N functionality with Versionable.  The problem is slightly different; [you can't even build the database when you nest I18N and Versionable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-135), but the solution he came up with might be useful.

In essence, he rolled his own Versionable.  Not the most pleasant prospect, but looking at how he implemented it might save you some time on your own [spike](http://blog.agilebuddy.com/2009/11/what-is-a-spike-in-scrum.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but should do what is required I think.

I haven't tested it but my understanding is that if you do a dql update() Versionable is not triggered.

Like this

```
   $result = $this->createQuery()
          ->update('MyOrder m')
          ->set('m.status', $var)
          ->execute();
```

But if you retrieve the object, change it and save thus:

```
$m = MyOrderTable::getInstance()->findOneById($id);
$m->setShippingPrice($price);
$m->save();
```

Then Versionable will be triggered so you should get a new version.

So you could use this to solve the problem.